# Creating MSI from command using devenv without installing Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, devenv

I am creating an MSI file by building using devenv command. I don't want to install visual studio. Is there an alternative to it?
Visual Studio is paid and I don't want to buy it.

**EDIT** :

I can't use MSBuild because I have .vdproj file which can't be build using MSBuild. So I use devenv.

Comment: If you don't want to install, use MSBuild - but there's also a [free version of VS](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/).

Comment: I can't use MSBuild. I have a vdproj file which can't be be build using MSBuild. And I guess the Community edition is not for comapies and only for "Free, fully-featured IDE for students, open-source and individual developers" and not commercial use ?